# UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to use CoreData to save data and today when I tried to test the App I got the message: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and an EXC_BREAKPOINT message.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext <-- Here is the error
```

And if I use UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate to call any other function from AppDelegate I get the same error.
Anybody knows a fix for that?

Comment: It's too soon. Put the code in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @vadian But then I can't use it in an IBAction :/

Comment: Declare both variables as `var` and implicit unwrapped optional and assign the values in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @vadian The error "Class "ViewController" has no intializers" is thrown if I do it like this: 
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

During initialization it is not guaranteed that `AppDelegate` is available.
Declare `managedObjectContext` as implicit unwrapped optional and assign the value in `viewDidLoad`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext 
    }

}
```

Or declare the variable as lazy initialized on the top level of the class.

```
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   return appDelegate.managedObjectContext
}()
```

Comment: Then try it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the AppDelegate class or with the managed object context, the context is supposed to be non-optional.

Comment: Posted my AppDelegate class